# oracle subtract then divide

Tags: sql, oracle

i need help getting this to work.  i simplified code but in reality i am doing counts from 3 different tables and need to do some math functions with the results.  specifically i need to get 2 results and subtract them from each other and then divide that answer from another count.

```
SELECT 
    (
        (
        SELECT 82 FROM DUAL
        ) * 100 

        /

        (select (
                    (
                    SELECT 100 as Test2 FROM DUAL
                            )
                    -
                    (
                    SELECT 50 as Test2 FROM DUAL
                            )
              ) from dual )               
    )
FROM DUAL;
```

i just got this to work if i put division on the same line and a space after the last parenthesis in first select statement, see below.  i am going to test some more real quick.
-- Worked:

```
SELECT 
    (
    SELECT 8200 FROM DUAL
    ) /
    (
      select (
                  (
                  SELECT 100 as Test2 FROM DUAL
                          )
                  -
                  (
                  SELECT 50 as Test2 FROM DUAL
                          )
            ) 
      from dual 
    )              

FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Why not `82 * 100 - 100 - 50`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko presumably because - as the OP has already said - the three different calls to dual represent calls to three different tables in their real-world situation.

Comment: @PurdyRA in what way is your query not working?

Comment: I got it working.  I am going to pause for a moment to test some more.  The division symbol had to be on same line and a space after the (* 100) to make it all of a sudden start working.

Comment: both your example statements give me an answer of 164. I'm struggling to see what your issue is? Btw, when you do `select (select 82 from dual) * 100...` you can just as easily do `select (select 82 * 100 from dual)...`. That will work even if your actual code is something along the lines of `select (select count(*) from some_table)...`, e.g. `select (select 100 * count(*) from some_table)...`

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation for SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref273) says:

> You can end a SQL command in one of three ways:
>
> - with a semicolon (;)
> - with a slash (/) on a line by itself
> - with a blank line
>
> ...
>
> A slash (/) on a line by itself also tells SQL*Plus that you wish to
>   run the command. Press Return at the end of the last line of the
>   command. SQL*Plus prompts you with another line number. Type a slash
>   and press Return again or click Execute. SQL*Plus executes the command
>   and stores it in the buffer.

That documentation largely applies to SQL Developer as well, though it always behaves as SQL*Plus does with SQLBLANKLINES off.

In your original query you'd put the slash on a line on its own; it's not just that it's on a different line to the previous expression, it's that it's on a different line to **both** the previous expression and and the next expression.

When that is run as a script the slash causes the first five lines to be executed as one statement, which generates the error "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis". The remaining 11 lines are then executed as a separate command, which generates "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" (against line 10 of that part).

As you've seen you just need to rearrange the layout a bit, but you can also simplify your example a bit to remove one extra `select ... from dual`:

```
SELECT ((SELECT 82 FROM DUAL) * 100)
  / ((SELECT 100 FROM DUAL) - (SELECT 50 FROM DUAL)) FROM DUAL;
```

You could also put your real queries into CTEs (or inline views), which might be clearer when you come to do the final calculation:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 82 AS val FROM DUAL),
  t2 AS (SELECT 100 AS val FROM DUAL),
  t3 AS (SELECT 50 AS val FROM DUAL)
SELECT (t1.val * 100) / (t2.val - t3.val)
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN t2
CROSS JOIN t3;

(T1.VAL*100)/(T2.VAL-T3.VAL)
----------------------------
                         164
```

This assumes each subquery/CTE gets a single row back, of course, but your existing code requires that too.

Answer (score 0):

i am using sql developer and it was erroring out because i had the division symbol on a different line than the previous value.  I posted code that was formatted correctly that got it to work.  Thank you to all those that replied.

Comment: It's not that it's on a different line to the previous value, exactly; it's that the `/` ended up on a line on its own, [which submits](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663) the first five lines as one statement (which gets ORA-00907), and the remaining lines are submitted as a separate statement (which gets ORA-00933). You get the same behaviour in SQL\*Plus. (Incidentally, you might find it clearer to use inline views or CTEs rather than subqueries; and you can lose at least one `select` and some parentheses with your pattern).